# How to open a popup in the center of the screen when zoomed in on mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, blazor

I have a problem with popups in my blazor webassembly application on mobile phones.

I have a website where it is necessary to zoom in on the mobile version. Then the user should be able to click on an object and a popup should open. This popup always opens on the top left of the original viewport but is not visible for the user who has zoomed in and changed the original viewport. I want the popup to open in the centre of the current viewport of the user, even if he as zoomed in. Does anyone know how to reach this goal?

currently i am using this css:

```
.modal {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        max-height: 500px;
        max-width: 600px;
        min-width: 300px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

screenshots:

[expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yadql.png)

[behaviour when moved away from of the initial viewport or when zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvIh1.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The translate value for transform is based off the size of the element, so that will center nicely.

```
.modal {
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.